# How to use Opera Mobile Widget

Tags: mobile, widget, opera

I face a problem in running Opera Mobile Widget. I try to download .wgt files from widgets.opera.com but I cannot run them on my mobile device. First, I try to run them on my Apple ipod 4, then on Android mobile phone and both the devices have Opera installed. However, it is impossible to run the widget. Please let me know the reason why and how to run the widgets. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Widgets do not run in Opera Mobile or Mini. However, you can run them on Android using this Labs build of the Opera widgets runtime: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/labs-widget-runtime-wac-1-0-compliant-golden-for-android/